# I am locked out of my WordPress site after changing site URL from Http to Https

Tags: ssl

Future home of something quite cool.
If you're the site owner, log in to launch this site

If you are a visitor, check back soon."

Comment: What kind of error do ou get when going to domain.com/wp-admin ???

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have access to your cPanel, or don't know how to make a database change, you can instead add these 2 lines to your wp-config.php file:

```
define( 'WP_SITEURL', 'http://example.com/' );
define( 'WP_HOME', 'http://example.com/' );
```

You'll of course want to change the urls to your actual urls. Just make sure you don't have the "https" but "http".

This will override your database entries.

Then go into your dashboard under settings and remove the https that you entered, hit save and you have fixed the problem.  If you added https via a plugin, you'll want to turn that plugin off.

You can then remove the two lines from your wp-config file and make sure everything still works.

**Two items to note.**

One. If you're using firefox and i believe Chrome.  They may continue to try to load to the SSL version of your site now that they have it it their history.  I have not gone into how to fix that here, but a quick google search will tell you how.

The other item. Just changing your db entries may not be the best idea as other it could damage serialized strings.

Answer (score 0):

If you have full control to Your website cpanel then you can change your worpress site url to https from https. Another thing you can do is you access your database from cpanel and from the listed tables you can change your site url. if you are still confused i can provide you detail image tips also.

Comment: Hmm. "you can change your worpress site url to https from https" does not make any sense ...

Comment: Login to your cpanel and go to php my admin, then find your db and there table wp_options, inside you will see URL of your website,2 fields site url and home url Change it how you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can also run this query in mysql to see if you missed any of the URL, and then changed it back from https to http

```
SELECT * FROM wordpress.wp_options where option_value LIKE "%example.com%";
```