# Plesk login inaccessible after changing site URL

Tags: wp-config, https, site-url, http

I was initially facing this issue: ([I am locked out of my WordPress site after changing site URL from Http to Https](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/254626/i-am-locked-out-of-my-wordpress-site-after-changing-site-url-from-http-to-https)).

I need to access wp-config to implement the given solution and was trying to access it through Plesk (I'm a beginner).

To open Plesk login, I read I need to go to <mysite.xyz>:8443. Since my site is unreachable, it seems, so is Plesk. My site is Windows-hosted, with the hosting set up by my client.

**Please help me understand how to reach Plesk or fix my issue.**

Comment: No, changing your WordPress configuration shouldn't block access to Plesk. You'll probably have to ask your client for help if they're the only ones with access to the hosting.

Comment: @Rup how do I log in then? I have credentials but the login screen itselr is at <mysite.xyz>:8443, and <mysite.xyz> is not accessible. It says the site can't be reached and the connection was reset -- I'm assuming because I changed the URL.

Comment: But you changed the URL for WordPress, not Plesk? And just from `http://mysite.xyz` to `https://mysite.xyz` ? Or did you change mysite.xyz too? If you did then I'd try the old site :8443. I'd guess the port 8443 link is HTTPS - you're definitely going to `https://mysite.xyz:8443` ?

Comment: However if you can't log in and you don't have shell access or similar you'll need to talk to whoever's hosting the server, which I guess means talking to your client.

Comment: I was trying to login at https://my.plesk.com/auth/login. I contacted my client and they were logging in using a different link they had from god-knows-where, and there I was able to log in with the same credentials I had. It's my first time using Plesk. It would be great if you could also tell me how I was supposed to reach that Plesk login link had my client not sent it to me.

Comment: I don't know Plesk, sorry. You'd have to ask them, or whoever set up the server.

Comment: For anyone who sees this thread, the plesk login was accessible through godaddy. I asked the client.